# getline() skipping over string line from text file

Tags: c++, file, getline

My project is supposed to basically sum up the value of all ints on a line and print the word in the next line that amount of times. However, something is causing it to skip over the string line where the word but I am getting the summed value right.

Input file:

```
1,2,3
word
2,3,4
word2
```

Here is my code:

```
int main() {

  std::ifstream in;
  std::ofstream out;
  std::string line;
  in.open("input.txt");
  out.open("output.txt");

  while(std::getline(in, line)){
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while(ss){
      std::string word;
      std::string number;
      int a = 0;
      while(std::getline(ss, number, ',')){
        a = a + atoi(number.c_str());}
      std::getline(ss, word);
      for (int z = 0; z < a; z++){
        out << word << ",";}
      out << "\n";
    }
  }
  return(0);
}
```

Output I'm getting:

```
,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
```

What I should be getting:

```
word,word,word,word,word,word

word2,word2,word2,word2,word2,word2,word2,word2
```

Comment: You are getting in the second loop number contents ”1”, "2", "3 word 2" , "3", "4 word2" and the empty word after the loop. You wish using operator >> instead of getline.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
std::getline(ss, word);
```

To this:

```
// Gets the next line in input.txt and stores it in the variable 'word'
std::getline(in, word);
```

This is because during the while loop, ss is emptied (exhausted) by the nested while loop (the 2nd while loop) and has no words when it's contents are inserted into the variable 'word'.

Final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    std::ifstream in;
    std::ofstream out;
    std::string line;
    in.open("input.txt");
    out.open("output.txt");

    while (std::getline(in, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        while (ss) {
            std::string word;
            std::string number;
            int a = 0;
            while (std::getline(ss, number, ',')) {
                a = a + atoi(number.c_str());
            }
            std::getline(in, word); // Changed line
            for (int z = 0; z < a; z++) {
                out << word << ",";
            }
            out << "\n";
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It's important to realize why no words were produced by the original code.  At the end of the inner `while` loop, `ss` is exhausted and doesn't contain any more characters.  So calling `getline` with it returns an empty string.

Comment: I am aware of that. I just wanted to keep the answer straight forward :). I have edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, I figured *you* were aware of it but obviously OP was confused.  Wanted to make sure the potential for confusion was eliminated.

Comment: Yes you're completely right. Thanks for informing me.